# How to pass a 2-D array's specific row as a 1-D array to a function in C?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a function which takes a *1-D array* as its parameter. The values that I want to pass to this function are present in a *specific row of a 2-D array*. How do I pass that row as a 1-D array to the function?

Comment: `array2D[rows]` or `&array2D[rows][cols /* 0 */]`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `nth` row of a 2d array (`array[x][y]`) to a function (`func`) using one of the following ways. Make sure to pass *`size`* of the the array (`nth row`)  to `func`.

- `func(array[n], y);`
- `func(&array[n][0], y);`
- `func(*(array+n), y);`

Each of the above expression evaluates to the same value (viz. the address of first element in `nth row`)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int *x, size_t n) {
    printf("%d\n", x[0]); /* marks[10][0] */
    if (n > 10) printf("%d\n", x[10]); /* marks[10][10] */
}

int main(void) {
    int marks[42][42] = {0};
    foo(marks[10], sizeof marks[10] / sizeof marks[10][0]);
}
```